# VS code debugger stopping

Tags: visual-studio-code, javascript-debugger, node-debugger

Whenever I want to launch VS code's debugger, it runs for a second or two and then stops with the message "Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
in the debugger console. [link to the debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9SJb.jpg)

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/controller\\get-form-contents.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try "${workspaceFolder}/controller/get-form-contents.js" - without the \\ slashes.